# Entity Framework using Sqlite.NET complains that APPLY joins are not supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sqlite

I am having problems executing the following join statement using Sqlite.NET with Entity Framework.

My setup is:

`.NET Framework v4`
`Entity Framework v6.0.0.0`
`SQLite.EF6 v1.0.99.0`
`SQLite.Linq v1.0.99.0`

```
using (var me = new ChinookContext())
{
    var screenset =
        from track in me.Tracks
        join genre in me.Genres on track.GenreId equals genre.GenreId
        join artist in me.Artists on track.Album.ArtistId equals artist.ArtistId
        into artists
        from artist in artists.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new TrackDTO
        {
            TrackId = track.TrackId,
            TrackName = track.Name,
            GenreId = genre.GenreId,
            GenreName = genre.Name,
            ArtistId = artist.ArtistId,
            ArtistName = artist.Name
        };
        foreach (var track in screenset)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(track.TrackId + ", " + track.TrackName + ", " + track.TrackPrice);
        }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> APPLY joins are not supported

and that's as inner as I can get without going through the stack trace.

The data model is based on the open source Chinook database.

[image: Chinook Data model]

The funny thing is I have used join statements in other Sqlite.NET queries and I have had no problems with this before.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the error and the stack trace:

> An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.APPLY joins are not supported
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__2()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__1()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>      at SqlLiteChinook.Qxx.SearchMusic() in D:\Dev\Showcase\ServerSqlLite\Xxx\Qxx.cs:line 36
>      at SqlLiteChinook.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Dev\Showcase\ServerSqlLite\ProgramServer.cs:line 28

Answer (score 1):

Using Lambda Expressions, below query would help to give the required results.

As there is good relationship between the tables, you can always use .Include method which would all rows of child table.

In the query below, I have done join between parent tables album and track. Album and track would include it's child tables artists and genre respectively.

```
var query3 = db.Albums.Include("Artists").Join(db.Tracks.Include("Genre"), aa => aa.TrackId, tr => tr.ID, (aa, tr) => new
            {
                aa,
                tr
            }).Select(Finalrow => new TrackDTO
            {
                TrackId = Finalrow.tr.ID,
                TrackName = Finalrow.tr.Name,
                GenreId = Finalrow.tr.GENREs.Select(g => g.ID).FirstOrDefault(),
                GenreName = Finalrow.tr.GENREs.Select(g => g.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                ArtistId = Finalrow.aa.Artists.Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                ArtistName = Finalrow.aa.Artists.Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault()

            }).OrderBy(t => t.TrackId);
```

Comment: Pardon me for the late reply as I have been busy. I learned something new using `.Include` in Linq instead of nasty `join` statements! I made some modifications to your query and it's working now. I have also arrived at my own conclusion. The problem is with the relationship of 'Track` and `Artist`. `Album` could be null so in my original query `track.Album.ArtistId equals artist.ArtistId` will throw an exception ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nagashree's solution after some modifications works. Big thank you to her. Here is the working version:

```
var query = db.Albums.Include("Artists")
.Join(db.Tracks.Include("Genre"), aa => aa.AlbumId, tr => tr.AlbumId,
(aa, tr) => new
{
    aa,
    tr
}).Select(Finalrow => new TrackDTO
{
    TrackId = Finalrow.tr.TrackId,
    TrackName = Finalrow.tr.Name,
    GenreId = Finalrow.tr.Genre.GenreId,
    GenreName = Finalrow.tr.Genre.Name,
    ArtistId = Finalrow.aa.ArtistId,
    ArtistName = Finalrow.aa.Artist.Name
}).OrderBy(t => t.TrackId);
```

The problem with my original query is that for `Track`, `Album` could be null so there is no way for you to reach `Artist`. Thus the Linq statement `track.Album.ArtistId equals artist.ArtistId` will throw an exception.

For old fashioned SQL coders like myself, here is the working query that I came up with using `join`:

```
var screenset =
from track in me.Tracks
join genre in me.Genres on track.GenreId equals genre.GenreId
join album in me.Albums on track.AlbumId equals album.AlbumId
into albums
from album in albums.DefaultIfEmpty()
join artist in me.Artists on album.ArtistId equals artist.ArtistId
into artists
from artist in artists.DefaultIfEmpty()             
select new TrackDTO
{
    TrackId = track.TrackId,
    TrackName = track.Name,
    GenreId = genre.GenreId,
    GenreName = genre.Name,
    ArtistId = artist.ArtistId,
    ArtistName = artist.Name
};
```

The trick here is to join `Album` `into` `albums` and check if it is null.

```
join album in me.Albums on track.AlbumId equals album.AlbumId
into albums
from album in albums.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Happy coding ;)

Comment: Thank you for posting modified query !! Good to know all alternative solutions